# How to merge data from multi query with different count of row TSQL?

Tags: datatable, merge

I have 3 query with the same column: Date, ProductCode, ProductDesc, TotalWeight, TaskPrice.

- Query A: ProductIN

Date             ProductCode     ProductDesc         TotalWeight       TaskPrice

01/01/2014       A1               A1                    3.25              225

01/02/2014       A2               A2                    3.25              200

01/02/2014       A3               A3                    3.25              300

01/03/2014       A4               A4                    3.25              150

- Query B: ProductOUT

Date             ProductCode     ProductDesc         TotalWeight       TaskPrice

01/03/2014       A2               A2                    3.25              200

01/03/2014       A3               A3                    3.25              300

- Query B: ProductSell

Date             ProductCode     ProductDesc         TotalWeight       TaskPrice

01/02/2014       A1               A1                      3.25              225

01/04/2014       A4               A4                      3.25              150

I want to merge data into one query with the result:

- Result:

Date       PCIN  PDIN TWIN  TPIN  PCOut  PDOut TWtOUT  TPOut   PCSell  PDSell   TWSell  TPSell

01/01/2014  A1    A1  3.25   225  NUll   NUll  NUll    NUll    NUll    NUll     NUll    NULL

01/02/2014  A2    A2  3.25   200  NUll   NUll  NUll    NUll    A1      A1       3.25    225

01/02/2014  A3    A3  3.25   300  NUll   NUll  NUll    NUll    NUll    NUll     NUll    NULL

01/03/2014  A4    A4  3.25   150  A2     A2    3.25    200     NUll    NUll     NUll    NULL

01/03/2014  NULL NULL NULL  NULL  A3     A3    3.25    300     NUll    NUll     NUll    NULL

01/04/2014  NULL NULL NULL  NULL  NUll   NUll  NUll    NUll    A4      A4       3.25    150

How can I do that? Please help me. Thanks a lot!